# Why do infinite-dimensional vector spaces usually have additional structure?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, gm.general-mathematics, vector-spaces

On Mathematics Stack Exchange, I asked the following question: [Why are infinite-dimensional vector spaces usually equipped with additional structure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4751895/why-are-infinite-dimensional-vector-spaces-usually-equipped-with-additional-stru) Although it received one good answer, I feel that there is more to be said, and a more technical explanation would be welcome. I thus ask a modified version of my question here.

Finite-dimensional vector spaces have a range of applications in pure mathematics. Although infinite-dimensional vector spaces are also widely studied, say, in functional analysis, it seems that most of the time they appear "naturally", they have additional structure, such as an inner product, norm, or a topology. My question is why this phenomenon occurs. Is there a reason for why "pure" infinite-dimensional vector spaces are not more pervasive?

(I also welcome answers that challenge the premise of the question. Perhaps finite-dimensional vector spaces are also most useful in applications when they are equipped with extra structure, or perhaps there are areas of mathematics which *do* make use of "pure" vector spaces, including infinite-dimensional ones.)

Comment: What if "infinite-dimensional vector spaces with extra structure" don't occur more often per se, but there's so little general theory for infinite-dimensional vector spaces without extra structure that only the ones with structure are observed & studied.

Comment: I think one crucial point you're missing is that finite dimensional vector spaces implicitly come with extra structure. There is only one Hausdorff topology compatible with each finite dimensional vector space. All norms are equivalent etc. The topology is somehow baked in. The only difference is in infinite dimensions you must make a choice.

Comment: @user479223: This is a useful perspective, thank you. However, I still find the asymmetry a little puzzling, in light of the fact that some applications of finite-dimensional spaces seem to not use this topology. For instance, as far as I know, modelling linear transformations such as rotations in $\mathbb R^n$ does not require us to use its topology (or inner product, or norm).

Comment: You might just as well ask "Why do infinite sets usually have extra structure?"

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452855/why-do-infinite-dimensional-vector-spaces-usually-have-additional-structure#comment1171389_452855), you are definitely using an inner product when you speak of rotations!  Otherwise, where do the angles come from?

Comment: A refinement is to note that most infinite-dimensional vector spaces one encounters have uncountable dimension, e.g. all Banach spaces, and to reduce to the simpler question of "Why do uncountable sets in ordinary math (outside set theory) usually have extra structure?"

Comment: @ Joe: following up @TomGoodwillie’s comment, don’t underestimate how much the same asymmetry you mention really does show up already in sets.  Almost all uncountable sets arising in nature (the reals, sets of infinite sequences, sets of functions…) *do* naturally carry extra structure, most often some topology or similar, and the vector space examples you give seem very much linked to that.  The idea that these sets “naturally come with” those topologies is well-studied in constructive mathematics (besides other areas) — e.g. work of Martín Escardó and collaborators.

Comment: Here's another perspective. From textbooks, we can get the impression that mathematical objects begin life as structureless sets, and acquire more structure as we add it. But in "real life," we usually start with *examples*, which come with oodles of structure, and much of our task as mathematicians is to strip away much of that structure in order to clarify certain logical relationships. From this perspective, the question isn't why infinite-dimensional vector spaces have additional structure. The question is why we can't strip away all the structure and still deduce the theorems we want.

Comment: (continued) When the question is phrased this way, we see that the answer is to be sought by looking at the examples and theorems we are most interested in. Often, in the examples of greatest interest, the questions we care about most can't even be *phrased* without extra structure.

Comment: @TimothyChow, you appear to be an avid reader of Penelope Maddy :-)

Comment: @MikhailKatz Guilty as charged! :-)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a supplement to the nice [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4751952/87579) that you got at MSE.

Much of the theory of infinite dimensional vector spaces is motivated by solving concrete problems in **analysis**. To solve differential equations, it is often profitable to use vector spaces of functions, and it is for this purpose that the theory of Banach spaces and other areas of functional analysis were developed. It is no surprise that in an analytic context one is concerned with questions of distance/absolute value, defining infinite sums, different notions of convergence etc.

On the other hand, as noted in Mikhail's [response](https://mathoverflow.net/a/452860), the algebraic theory of infinite dimensional vector spaces is not particularly interesting on its own.  For the most part, one of the following two things happens

1. There is an entirely analogous theory to the finite dimensional case (e.g. there is one isomorphism class of vector space for each cardinality of set; a linear transformation is determined uniquely by its values on a basis; a linear transformation is invertible iff the kernel and cokernel vanish etc.).
2. There is no possible analogous theory to the finite dimensional case, without introducing some notion of convergence/topology (e.g. there aren't infinite dimensional determinants that you can use to detect invertibility).

This makes the algebraic theory less interesting than the analytic one.

In summary, the theory of infinite dimensional vector spaces has an analytic flavor because the historical motivations and applications are analytic, and most of the *new* nontrivial theory lies in an analytic direction.

**Edit:** One final comment: so-called "pure" infinite dimensional vector spaces actually do appear in mathematical practice quite frequently (at least in algebra).  But there typically aren't classes or books devoted specifically to them, for the reasons mentioned above.

Answer (score 13):

We can get some insight into this question by considering matroid theory.

But first, I think the question is phrased in a somewhat misleading way: "Why is there not much interesting theory of infinite-dimensional vector spaces with no extra structure, whereas there is an interesting theory of finite-dimensional vector spaces with no extra structure?" In my opinion, this is not a fair comparison, because **finite-dimensionality is the extra structure**. In other words, the basic object is a vector space, with no mention of cardinality. It should not be too surprising that if we impose some extra structure on a vector space—namely, finite-dimensionality—then we get a richer theory than if we don't impose any extra structure.  All over mathematics, we find that finiteness hypotheses yield rich dividends.

But in the particular case of vector spaces, we can say a little more. [Matroids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid) are a generalization of vector spaces, obtained by writing down axioms for (linear) independence.  From its beginnings, matroid theory has focused almost exclusively on *finite* matroids. Given the success of matroid theory, it is natural to ask, why doesn't there seem to be a well-developed theory of infinite matroids?  Part of the answer is that one things that makes matroid theory work so well is **duality**. In the finite case, it is easy to see how to define duality and to derive important consequences from duality. In the infinite case, though, it turns out to be a very difficult problem to develop a satisfactory duality theory.  It was not until 2010 that a viable candidate for infinite matroid theory with duality was found, in the paper [Axioms for infinite matroids](https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.3919), by Bruhn et al.  This struggle in matroid theory perhaps sheds some light on why vector spaces with no extra structure do not have a very rich theory at this time.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I think it is useful to think of finite-dimensionality as being the extra structure. One might object that infinite-dimensionality is also "extra structure" to the extent that it tells us something about the cardinality of a basis. One answer to this objection I came up with was the following: finiteness hypotheses are very useful in preventing pathological behaviour; however, the same cannot be said for infiniteness hypotheses.

Comment: Moreover, it is arguably quite unnatural to hypothesise that a vector space *is* infinite-dimensional; rather, we should hypothesise that it is not necessarily infinite-dimensional (which is equivalent to just studying general vector spaces, of course). I think this is similar to how many theorems about noncommutative rings are not really about rings which are noncommutative *per se*, but rather rings which are not necessarily commutative.

Comment: I think this is similar to the point of view you are advocating in your answer, but I don't want to put words in your mouth, so I'd be interested to hear how you would answer the objection.

Comment: @Joe It is certainly possible in principle for an "infiniteness hypothesis" to prevent pathological behavior. For example, a vector space cannot be the union of finitely many proper subspaces, *if* the field is infinite. (This fact comes up in the context of [prime avoidance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_avoidance_lemma), which is a useful tool in commutative algebra.) But I think this sort of thing is rare, not just in linear algebra, but in mathematics more generally. I like your comparison with commutativity.

Comment: @Joe I ran across a related MO question that you might find interesting: [A vector space has the same dimension as its dual if and only if it is finite dimensional](https://mathoverflow.net/q/13322).

Answer (score 9):

This remark might perhaps be of interest, despite being tangential to your query.  Given how daunting the Schwartz approach to distributions, which involved duality theory for rather exotic locally convex spaces of test functions, was, there were attempts to simplify it by defining distributions to be linear forms on the space of smooth functions of compact support, without demanding continuity.  This is tantamount to ignoring the topology on the latter.  As I recall, it was feasible to use this approach to obtain a basic theory which was sufficient for the requirements of (some) mathematical physicists.  This is perhaps not surprising, given that there are versions of set theory under which all linear functionals on such function spaces are automatically continuous (Solovay, Schwartz, Garnir). Unfortunately, at the moment I have no access to resources which would allow me to provide references but the comprehensive multi-volume treatise on mathematical physics by R. Hermann springs to mind.

Comment: I doubt very much that this *algebraic distribution theory* is fruitful for applications. For example, Schwartz distributions are locally derivatives of continuous functions which yields one possible physical interpretation. Nothing like this holds for most algebraic distributions.

Answer (score 9):

An infinite-dimensional vector space without any additional structure carries no more information than the cardinality of its [Hamel basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)#Hamel_basis).  In modern mathematics, infinite-dimensional vector spaces are studied in a number of fields such as analysis, functional analysis, etc.  To go beyond set theory, one needs additional structure.  For example, as soon as you add a [Hilbert space structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2175218/72694), you get the basic framework for Fourier series, quantum mechanics, etc.

A finite-dimensional vector space is also characterized by the cardinal of its basis, but finite cardinals (i.e., natural numbers) have more structure than infinite ones, such as their semiring structure.  This has immediate applications such as [topological K-theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_K-theory), etc.

Comment: A finite-dimensional vector space is likewise determined by  the cardinality of a basis.

Comment: @AndreasBlass, would this suggest that finite cardinals have more applications in ordinary mathematics than infinite ones?

Comment: This *answer* turned out to be more controversial than I expected.  For users who can't see the break-down into upvotes and downvotes: there are currently *three* downvotes.  Would the downvoters step forward and explain themselves?  I would be happy to strive to improve my *answer*.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: I didn't downvote (in fact, I upvoted), but I think Andreas Blass's comment is a reasonable objection: your logic would seem to suggest that bare finite-dimensional vector spaces are also uninteresting, because they carry only a single cardinal invariant.

Comment: @SamHopkins, thanks, I tried to address this.  There are currently *four* downvotes already :-)

Answer (score 6):

In many situations, *extra structure* is used only as tool to answer questions which have nothing to do with that structure. For example, let $P(D)(f)=\sum_{|\alpha|\le m} c_\alpha \partial^\alpha f$ be linear partial differential operator of finite order with constant coefficients. For every convex subset $\Omega\subseteq \mathbb R^d$, $P(D)$ is a surjective linear map $C^\infty(\Omega)\to C^\infty(\Omega)$.

This theorem of Malgrange has nothing to do with the *extra structure* of $C^\infty(\Omega)$ being a Fréchet space which is a key ingredient in the proof.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I find this perspective convincing (with regard to the question at hand). I mean, you're technically right of course. But with the same reasoning one can also say that Malgrange's theorem has nothing to do with $C^\infty(\Omega)$ being a vector space.

Comment: But the vector space structur is needed to define the **linear** partial differential operator.

Answer (score 4):

This question is almost similar to the following question. Why do we need more structures on sets, for example vector space or manifold etc? In mathematics people develop notions like sets or infinite dimensional vector spaces not only for the intention for generalisations. These notions should also help us to extract deep mathematical facts. Many times infinite dimensional vector spaces arise from differential equations, operator algebras or abstract algebra etc. Often they have some extra structures and to study them we impose those extra structures. Also often our guiding examples are finite dimensional. For example if you look at local theory of Banach spaces. The idea is to consider finite dimensional phenomenon which are dimension independent. Often we should be able to take limits in infinite dimensional spaces at least for analysts. So we need some more criterion to make us enable to take limits. This idea is prevalent in all analysis where we consider infinite dimensional vector space. Also to talk about limits we need some notion of topology and the space has to be complete also. Thus analysts more or less consider topological vector spaces which are complete.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that people are often taught that mathematics is the study of sets and functions. The truth is that *topological spaces* are more relevant in practice, and *continuous functions* are more important than unrestricted functions. The reason is that for some topological spaces $(X, T)$, [all computable functions are also continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_analysis). The truth of this statement has been made rigorous for certain topological spaces (Second Countable + Locally Compact?). Speculating more generally, when making the statement rigorous, the topological spaces in question need to be restricted in certain ways, namely to satisfy some **separation axiom** and **countability axiom**. The separation axiom is usually *sobriety*, which is weaker than Hausdorff. The countability axiom might be as weak as Lindelöf. Anyway, this rules out many topologies on vector spaces of infinite dimension.

If one adopts the philosophy that sets+functions are wrong - and topological spaces+continuous functions are right - then this undermines the assumption the question makes that *algebraic vector spaces* are any more basic than *topological vector spaces*.

Comment: You may want to be more explicit about how your analysis accounts for the difference between finite-dimensional and infinite-dimensional cases.

Comment: @MikhailKatz Sure. If you topologise everything, then your field $k$ becomes a topological field, and $k^n$ automatically carries a certain topology. If the topology on $k$ were something nice, then the topology on $k^n$ would still be nice. The same thing wouldn't be true if $n$ in $k^n$ were an uncountable cardinal number.

Comment: I'm not tooootally happy with this answer, because it's vague. It tries to convey a certain philosophy that I think is often true.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452855/why-do-infinite-dimensional-vector-spaces-usually-have-additional-structure#comment1171624_452945), doesn't $k$ being a topological field (or ring) imply that $k^n$ is a topological ring with the product topology, regardless of the size of $n$? \\ Also, it may be worth noting that sets and functions are topological spaces (with the discrete topology) and continuous functions, so that we gain generality by considering an apparently special case!

Comment: @LSpice My answer mentions **separation axioms** and **countability axioms**. The discrete topology on many vector spaces would violate every countability axiom. Likewise, $k^n$ for $n$ an uncountable cardinal number might do the same. I tried to make the point that maybe these examples of topological vector spaces with the discrete topology are *not* very natural ones.

Comment: @LSpice Not sure why I'm addressing this to you, but anyway: My answer was really in the same spirit as [Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine's comment to the question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452855/why-do-infinite-dimensional-vector-spaces-usually-have-additional-structure/452945#comment1171532_452855).

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/452855/why-do-infinite-dimensional-vector-spaces-usually-have-additional-structure/452945#comment1171627_452945), I didn't mean to suggest that discrete topological spaces were particularly interesting—as you point out, most of the interesting ones violate countability axioms—only that they *do* fit under the topological umbrella, so that we gain strictly *more* expressive power by considering all spaces to be equipped with topologies.